# Notation $\mathbb{R}${${\partial _x} + y{\partial _z}, {\partial_y}$}

Tags: differential-forms, vector-bundles, contact-geometry

I'm reading Ko Honda's notes on Contact Geometry (course page [link](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Ehonda/Math%20234%20winter%202019%20syllabus.html); notes [link](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Ehonda/math599/notes.pdf)) and ran into a bit of notational confusion. When (page 2, after HW4) talking about the standard contact form on $\mathbb{R}^3$ (which is given by $\alpha_0=dz-ydx$), Honda denotes the kernel of this form by:

$ker(\alpha_0)=\xi_0=\mathbb{R}${${\partial _x} + y{\partial _z}, {\partial_y}$}

Is anyone able to make sense of this notation for me? I'm also a little confused on how to compute the kernel of a form (which I've read is a tangent bundle by this link:[Is the kernel of a differential form a subset of $M$ or of $TM$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3743153/is-the-kernel-of-a-differential-form-a-subset-of-m-or-of-tm)) which might be helpful as well (if someone could clarify how that kernel was calculated given this form).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The kernel of the one form $\alpha_0 : \mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R$ is dimension 2, and the two tangent vectors in the curly braces are in the kernel. I suppose $\mathbb R\{\}$ means to take the span?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}\{\partial_x+y\partial_z,\partial_y\}$ is another notation for the span over $\mathbb{R}$ of $\{\partial_x+y\partial_z,\partial_y\}$.

To check this is indeed the kernel lets sub in an arbitrary vector.  At any point $p\in \mathbb{R}^3$, $\alpha_0(p)$ is simply a linear functional on $T_p\mathbb{R}^3$.  Therefore, let us consider the vector $$v=a\partial_x+b\partial_y+c\partial_z\in T_p\mathbb{R}^3$$ where $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$.  Then $$\alpha_0(p)(v)=(dz-ydx)(v)=dz(v)-ydx(v).$$
Since the one forms $dx,dy,dz$ are dual to $\partial_x,\partial_y,\partial_z$ they simply pull out the corresponding components. Therefore $$\alpha_0(p)(v) =dz(v)-ydx(v) = c-ya.$$  Finally, if $v\in \text{ker}\,\alpha_0$ then $\alpha_0(v)=0$ which would imply $c=ya$.  Therefore, we can write an arbitrary element of the kernel as $$v=a\partial_x+b\partial_y+ya\partial_z=a(\partial_x+y\partial_z)+b\partial_y$$ for arbitrary constants $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ which is the same as saying $$\text{ker}\,\alpha_0=\text{span}_{\mathbb{R}}\{{\partial_x+y\partial_z,\partial_y}\}=\mathbb{R}\{\partial_x+y\partial_z,\partial_y\}$$